# The magnetite is in which type of magma

Tags: geology, geochemistry, igneous

In which type of magma can I find magnetite? Peraluminous or peralkaline? I've been looking and the peraluminous magma have a lot of oxides so I thought it would be reduced magma so it would have magnetite but I'm not pretty sure.

Answer (score 1):

Probably both but I'd expect to see more in a peraluminous melt. The more [mafic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mafic) the melt the more iron based mineralisation you're going to see.